# How to configure phpmyadmin to show values in id desc order?

Tags: phpmyadmin

In `phpMyAdmin` I'd like to see newer rows on top, that is tables should be displayed sorted by DESC id. Here are the specs:

```
nginx/1.18.0
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.19
PHP version: 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.19
phpMyAdmin: 5.2.1 (up to date)
```

I have added this line to `config.inc.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['TablePrimaryKeyOrder'] = 'DESC';
```

and then cleared the cookie and logged in again.
As it did not work, I also added these:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_sort_order'] = 'DESC';
$cfg['DefaultOrder'] = 'DESC';
```

But it had no effect either.  These are common solutions I found upon searching.

So I'm wondering what is the right way to do so?